# what is this panel and how can i make it gone?

Tags: interface

[image]

this panel appeared after i did something what I'm not sure, and also the '~' key stopped working with it. Doe's any one know how can i make it disappear, and make the '~' key back to work again like before? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press "T" ("Toolbar") to let it go away. The panel is made for people not know how to enter the displayed modes of manipulating objects.

Comment: thank you very much